# Why is python3 in another folder? not in /usr/bin/python

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, homebrew

I tried to install `brew install python3`
The result is:

```
python@3.9 3.9.7 is already installed but outdated
Warning: You are using macOS 10.14.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
(...)
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
(...)
Error: python@3.9: Failed to download resource "gdbm"
Download failed: https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gdbm/gdbm-1.22.tar.gz
```

I don't understand what I should do now?

PS: i checked the versions of python installed, but i cannot see 3.9.7

```
ls -ls /usr/bin/python*
```

gave me this result

```
32 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66880  9 dec  2020 /usr/bin/python
 0 -rwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel    925 18 aug  2018 /usr/bin/python-config
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75  6 mrt  2019 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82  6 mrt  2019 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
32 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66880  9 dec  2020 /usr/bin/pythonw
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76  6 mrt  2019 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

If i type `python3` then it opens up the shell, so it exists:

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep  3 2021, 12:36:14) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

In this shell, i typed in these instructions to find the path:

```
for p in sys.path:
  print(p)
```

and it gave me

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

so it's in a weird folder now, why is that?